# element moving problems when resizing

Tags: html, css

Having problem with button whenever i resize the page the button moves help please :

```html
<div class="bg-image">
  <img src="http://unplugged.ee/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/lightroom_vintage_03-1170x839-e1425571518543.jpg">
  <div class="poga">
     <a class="myButton" href="#">Button text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ry3ur710/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I adjusted the formatting of your code snippet to make it more readable. When you have more than one line of code, the best approach is to press ENTER twice before the start, then press SPACEBAR four times to indent it. That triggers the "code" formatting. Press ENTER once at the end of a line, and indent each following line correctly. Or press SHIFT+Enter so that the tool makes the first indent (four spaces) for you. Press ENTER twice at the end of the code block.

Comment: Please describe where your button is positioned, originally, and HOW your button moves.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with your `.bg-image img` class. Try applying this update it to this:

```
.bg-image img {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

The line of code `width: 100%;` was causing the problem.

Comment: After that i had a problem with the image it isnt width: 100% anymore